# Is a constant pointer to a constant data legal?

Tags: c

Is the code `int const*const pointer1=&constantVariable;` legal?

If it isn't, what is the correct way of specifying it?

Comment: Do you mean `int * const * pointer`? (also how is `constantVariable` declared?)

Comment: I'm not sure; maybe that's the legal way of achieving what I'm trying.

Comment: Well it depends. `int * const * pointer` has 2-levels of *indirection* (like `int **a;`). If `constantVariable` is not a pointer itself, then `int * const * pointer` is wrong. In that case you would need `int * const pointer`. (e.g. `const int i = 5; int * const p = (int * const)&i;` (which is a *pointer to const int*) Compared to `const int * p = &i;` (a *const int pointer*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK!
In `int const*const pointer1=&constantVariable`, the first `const` indicates that you couldn't change the value by *pointer1; the second `const` indicates the value of pointer itself(an address) couldn't be changed too. Actually pointer1 can point to a constant integer, even a normal variable.But it can't be set twice.